# Ограничение работы счётчика input по переменной

Tags: jquery, input

Самостоятельное изменение `input` запрещено. Есть кнопки - "Плюс" и "Минус". По нажатию "Плюс" значение `input` изменяется на единицу в положительную сторону, по нажатию "Минус" - в отрицательную. Нужно ограничить максимальное значение `input` переменной. Например, количество доступных товаров - 25 (в некую переменную попадает 25), нужно ограничить максимальное значение `input` цифрой 25.

```
var minus = $('.minus');
var plus = $('.plus');
    plus.click(
                function () {
                    var input = $(this).parent().find('input');
                    input.val(parseInt(input.val()) + 1);
                    input.change();
                });

    minus.click(
                function () {
                    var input = $(this).parent().find('input');
                    var count = parseInt(input.val()) - 1;
                    count = count < 1 ? 1 : count;
                    input.val(count);
                    input.change();
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, как-то так:

```
var max_count = 25;
var minus = $('.minus');
var plus = $('.plus');
    plus.click(
                function () {
                    var input = $(this).parent().find('input');
                    var count = parseInt(input.val()) + 1;
                    count = count > max_count ? max_count: count;
                    input.val(count);
                    input.change();
                });
```

Comment: Vitali, спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно использовать `input type=number` в котором уже есть кнопки уменьшения/увеличения. Остается только запретить ручной ввод.

```js
$("#ItenNumber").keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" max="25" min="0" value="1" id="ItenNumber" />
```

Comment: Perkovec, можно, но, если я не ошибаюсь, не все браузеры поддерживают данный тип. Да у меня эти кнопки и в вёрстку не впишутся, больно страшные)

Comment: @Torawhite Ну ладно, может кто-то будет искать и наткнется на мой ответ)